# "my chances of winning" vs. "chances of me winning"

Tags: gerunds, personal-pronouns, grammatical-case, saxon-genitive

what is the difference between *my chances of winning* and *chances of me winning*? I've come across the usage of both.

Comment: The difference is that in _my chances of winning_, _my_ modifies _chances_ and therefore must be possessive, while in _chances of me winning_, _me_ is the subject of a gerund clause, and therefore may be either objective (_me_) or possessive (_my_) because there are two complementizers for gerund complements, one using objective subjects and the other using possessive. Both are grammatical here. This is not true with the first sentence, because only a possessive pronoun can modify a noun, not a nominative or objective one.

Comment: They're both valid and in common use with "sentient subject" [pro]nouns, but the genitive form is probably less likely in other "possessive" contexts with *inanimate* subjects. Where in any case we're sometimes effectively *obliged* to use the "objective" form. You'll probably never hear *"Its chances of raining are low"*, which would practically always be expressed as *"The chances of it raining are low"* (not *chances of **its** raining*).

Comment: @JohnLawler There's also the case of *the chances of mine winning*, using a different sort of possessive. :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: As for _chances of its raining_, why bother inflecting a dummy subject, after all? And why even bother with a verb when what you need is a noun, to be the object of _of_? _Chances of rain_ is what I'd say.

Comment: @John Lawler: I see what you mean. What I said about "inanimate" subjects was unthinking (its chance of being incisive was always minimal! :). It's only "obligatory" to avoid the genitive **s** (not, in this case, the genitive **'s**) with a ***dummy*** subject "it".

Comment: ...actually, checking Google Books it seems quite a few people are happy to write about [*the chance of **its** raining*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22chance+of+its+raining%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). At least I can "almost" live with their choice though, which is more than I can say for the benighted few who wrote about [*chance of **it's** happening*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22chance+of+it%27s+happening%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl).

Answer (score 1):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> The difference is that in *my chances of winning*, *my* modifies *chances* and therefore must be possessive, while in *chances of me winning*, *me* is the subject of a gerund clause, and therefore may be either objective (*me*) or possessive (*my*) because there are two complementizers for gerund complements, one using objective subjects and the other using possessive. Both are grammatical here. This is not true with the first sentence, because only a possessive pronoun can modify a noun, not a nominative or objective one.

Answer (score -1):

Caveat, This answer is probably wrong, and by the way I pronounce the first a in caveat as a long a, which is probably also wrong. But I know what I think, and I can't figure out from the comments by the experts above, whether I am way off base or not. Consider the following sentences: 1) I heard the baby crying. 2) I heard the baby's crying. I think both sentences are grammatical, but they have slightly different meanings. Sentence 1) says I heard the baby and when I heard the baby it was crying. Sentence 2) says I heard crying and it was the crying of the baby. In these sentences the difference is so slight that no one would use 2), which sounds stilted. But I would certainly say, "the chances of *my* winning are not great, rather than "the chances of *me* winning are not great." If you look at the NBC Handbook of Pronunciation, which was compiled in 1943, you will find my pronunciation of "caveat," and I suspect if you let me go back far enough I can find support for *my*  insisting on "my" rather than "me."